# Is possible to use this angularJS html attribute: ng-include="{{...}}"?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm working on a small project that should load posts in a webpage. I think that I could do that fast using the angular ng-repeat to create the posts and then use ng-include to load the post formatted content, which is a small HTML page. Here is the code:

```
<section ng-controller="PostController as posts" ng-show="!$first">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts.info">
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <div ng-include="posts/{{post.content}}"></div> //here is the problem
        <span class="date">{{post.createdOn}}</span>
        <span class="author">{{post.author}}</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

I import the content for the title, the date and the  author from a JSON, and it works.
When I load the page, I see that the html page that should load is missing. I'll store the main text of a post in a folder called "posts", and inside this, there will be the posts.
So I looked at the rendered page for the issue, and I saw that AngularJS seems commenting what can't load: I saw in fact `<!-- ngInclude: '{{post.content}}' -->`.

So my question is: how can I tell AngularJS to read from a HTML tag attribute the result of `{{ }}`?

Comment: <div ng-include="'posts/{{post.content}}'"></div>

Comment: That doesn't work, the browser says that it cant find the URL (and it don't get the `{{post.content}}` as a link, but as `%7B&7Bpost.content%7D%7D`. Thanks anyway for told the `"'...'"` error!

Comment: If you use ng-include i think it will show all the included files on the website or shown any error i think it is not possible to do... The correct way html bind friend...

Comment: Have you tried to use ng-bind-html? This will bind html content to your div, perhaps it´s better practice than including various html files.  What is the content of your "post.content" variable?

Comment: I have to check if this works... now it get the URL, but I have to sanitize it. Thanks @Fedaykin for told me about ng-bind-html!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Plunker that [demonstrates](http://plnkr.co/edit/6afCemMghJ6sqSD06wnP?p=preview) how this can work. The upshot is that you don't need {{}}. Just specify the Angular expression in double quotes like so:

```
<div ng-include="post.content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this work:

```
<div ng-include="'post/'+ post.content">
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I fixed my problem!
I discovered that it works if i **write the following code**:

```
  <div ng-include="'posts/testPost.html'" class="ng-binding"></div>
```

Don't ask me for the theory part behind this, because I haven't still understand completely how it works.

Comment: So, you don't need a dynamic `ng-include` at the first place?